# Subscribe to RabbitMQ queue with SailsJs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-amqp

How to subscribe to RabbitMQ queue with SailsJs (without waterline adapter).
Only with use of `amqp.node` https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node. And without client request.

From my understanding controllers are for http request. What I want is to get something to connect to RabbitMQ queue and do some stuff. But this should not happen from http request.